# Java Sockets Read Timed Out

Tags: java, sockets, timeout

So I have inherited a project with a Java component.  Essentially a Java app is siting on a server waiting for multiple devices to connect and "send" data where Java then writes this data to MySQL.

The data is very small, example string below:

The string is: 58 FC DB 30 01 B9 80 BC 55 DC 99 3B 02 1A 07 00 27 0F 00 00 00 00 01 00 70 AC 00 00 63 F8 01 0B 11 06 1E 05 00 00 00 00

For some reasons MANY times per day we get a "Read timed out" error becuase our threshold of 20 seconds is met.

I'm more a PHP developer than a Java expert.

Can anyone suggest items I might look at to improve and/or better diagnose this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What problem? You set a 20-second read timeout, the peer didn't send anything for 20 seconds, you got the timeout. That's what's supposed to happen. If you think it's too short, increase it. Or investigate the peer, if you can.

Comment: EJP, thanks so much for your comment, I really appreciate your time.  I guess I was wondering if there was anything I might look at on this side (Java side) that could be causing the delay.